# API Search on Rails Search Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Probably poorly worded subject, I'm recently picking up Rails and trying to make some improvements on an old project.

I'm using a gem that handles the Steampowered API Calls - https://github.com/Olgagr/steam-web-api

And I'm rendering it with

```
<% if current_user %>
     <% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(current_user.player_steam_id) %>
     <% data = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true) %>
     <% game = data.games %>
         <% game.each do |f| %>
         <%= f['playtime_2weeks'] %>
            <% if f['img_icon_url'].empty? %>
                <img src='http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png'>
            <% else %>
                <img src='http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/<%=    f['appid'] %>/<%= f['img_icon_url'] %>.jpg'>
            <% end %>
        <%= f['name'] %><br>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I added in Active Directory record and modified it, so that it auto populates the field in the users category with the data.

Essentially I'm trying to do the same thing next to it, but with a search. "current_user.player_steam_id" would be replaced with a specific query return.

Right off the bat, even if I could get it to work (I was resorting to using JS Swaps, which worked, but wasn't the way I feel like it should work) I would literally have two of the same code blocks next to each other.

I believe at this point is when I would use a form_helper and place this in a form, and render it... but how do I render it dynamically? I've been reading a lot of the Active:Directory:RoR Tutorials, and I used it to make my create fields, but I'm unsure how to make it for a dynamic section.

For small example.

Before:

```
|    Section 1    |     Section 2    | Section 3|
|CurrentUsersGames|Steam# To Search? |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|  [Input Field]   |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|                  |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|                  |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|                  |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|                  |    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|                  |    TBD   |
```

After Search:

```
|    Section 1    |     Section 2    | Section 3|
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
|CurrentUsersGames|SearchedUsersGames|    TBD   |
```

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.
(The <% if current_user %> stops it from breaking if they're not logged in)

Edit: Added 'before' and 'after' clarification. Essentially I'm trying to get the middle div to go from a search field to the results of the API response.

Comment: `I would use a form_helper and place this in a form, and render it... but how do I render it dynamically?` can you show us what this attempt would look like? I am finding it really hard to figure out what you actually want... so an attempt at doing this would help me to understand what you actually need... especially what do you mean by "how do I render it dynamically?" - all code is dynamic, and the word is ambiguous in this context... what part is not dynamic? can you show us what it'd look like if it was static and then tell us what you want it to do when it's dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for insight @TarynEast - I added a before. In hindsight I guess my graph was confusing. My graph is what I'm "trying" to get as a final product. I can make it happen by hardcoding in the 'SteamID' in the search, but again - Then I literally have 2 of the exact same blocks of code, rendering it twice for one small part difference.

Comment: If all you're doing is reducing code duplication in a views, then that is what partials are for. Make the partial accept any dynamic variables, and pass them in as locals... then call the partial twice (once with `current_user.player_steam_id` and once with the search-result) ?

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast - I'll look more into Partials. That must be what I needed. My searching kept bringing back form::helpers which didn't quite seem like what I needed. Would I do something like
[This?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Comment: cool. yeah I am familiar with those times when you just don't know what you need to ask for :) I'll write up a quickie partial example as an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mainly after de-duping your code in your view, then probably what you want is a partial template.

here's an example of what you'd have in the original template:

```
<% if user_logged_in? %>
  <% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(current_user.player_steam_id)
     owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true).game
     search_games = player.your_game_search_here %>

 <%= render :partial => 'game_list', :locals => {:games => owned_games, :header => "Games owned by #{player.name}"} %>
 <%= render :partial => 'game_list', :locals => {:games => search_games, :header => "Filtered Game search list title here"} %>

<% end %>
```

and here's what would go in your partial (which you'd name `_game_list.html.erb` in this example)

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% games.each do |game| %>
  <%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
  <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
    <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's really cool. I did something similar for my original User view, I just couldn't figure out if the partial was created in a separate file, or not (I see it is).

Thanks a lot for the help! Greatly appreciated it. 

Random addition: Is this a good method - Like "best practice"? I'm not sure when to use Helpers vs Partials vs Forms, etc...

Comment: Yep, I use partials all the time to de-dup my views - it's the best thing :)

Comment: So I changed it a bit - Your partial was very useful in understanding what I need (I probably mis-explained. I was trying to make a search field for someone ELSE'S games. So a field you put in their SteamID then it searches.)

However, I think I can make it by changing very little of your code, however I have an issue.
`<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(:steamId)
     owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>`
I followed your structure and did `:steamId => ########` however it isn't rendering it. I've seen numerous articles showing that is how it's done, but no bueno?

Comment: Yeah I figured it'd be different - the example was just a rough-guide for you to change up the way you needed :)
Sounds like you should create a new question for that new bug :) add a link in the comments when you write it up and I'll take a look.

Comment: Here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965785/pushing-a-locale-variable-to-partial-in-rails-4-2