# Pushing a Locale Variable to Partial in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a partial that pulls the list of games someone has in their Steam Library

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(steamId)
 owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
<% owned_games.each do |game| %>
<%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
<% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
<%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
<% end %>
<%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

And it's base view feeds off of current_user.player_steam_id - A field in SQL.
Originally this was nice to show only your present games, but I want to do a few things with it.

A) When you check someones profile, you see their list.
B) You can search with a users ID, to pull the query results.

My initial issue is using (XXXXXX is actually a number, so I don't stringify it(Do I?)

```
   <%= render :partial => 'game_list', :locals => {:header => "Welcome to His Page!", :steamId => XXXXXXXXXX } %>
```

And the "Welcome to His Page!" is getting passed, but I'm having a lot of issues getting :steamId to render.

In the partial view I've tried rendering it with `<%= steamId %>` `<% steamId %>` and `:steamId`

The current and `:steamId` are the only two that don't break the page, but it doesn't render anything. I'm fairly new to this so trying to figure it out, but I've found numerous posts that say I'm doing it right.

I'm welcome to any input.

Also - Since I plan to use this widely, should I look into making it a Controller? Or would the partial suffice? 
(P.S. I'm typically a Node guy, so I tried debug+console.log(steamId) a lot to see how it's rendering, but I didn't get results in console.log, and debug didn't do anything. How do you normally debug something like this in RoR?

Thanks for any input!

EDIT:

Additional Info:

The issue with this was partially in the partial.

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(steamId)
owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
<% owned_games.each do |game| %>
<%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
<% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
<%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
<% end %>
<%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

By modifying it to owned_games definition, and player definition are on separate lines, it resolved successfully. This was just a not-reviewing-what-I-copied/pasted fail on my part.

Resolved code:

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% puts steamId %>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(steamId) %>
     <% owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
     This is my steam ID <%= steamId %>
<% owned_games.each do |game| %>
  <%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
  <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
    <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

However, I am only able to have it render if it pulls the player_steam_id from the DB.

So for instance if I have 
`:steamId => 76561198017108025`

It won't work, but if I have

`:steamId => User.player_steam_id` it does work.

(Again, 'User' has a column in SQL that stores their player_steam_id)

I want to be able to call this on the 'Submit' of a search button, which is why I'm trying to see how to get the render to work with a specific number.

Why could that be the case? I have tried logging steamId with the view, and I see it being passed through as a normal integer. My only logical assumption is that the view loads, calls the API with 'steamId' THEN renders steamId but I'm just guessing?

**Update Trial-n-Error**

So I tried out using something like

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% appCall = steamId %>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(appCall) %>
<% owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
<%= appCall %>
<%= owned_games.success %>
<% owned_games.each do |game| %>
  <%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
  <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
    <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

I am able to get an output with the puts, and also be using the 'player.success' function of the API. Which returns "True", and puts steamId and app both render out the ID.

I also tested printing out the entire array before the 'for', and did notice it gives me all of the data.
`true #<OpenStruct count=31, games=[{"appid"=>300, "name"=>"Day of Defeat: Source", "playtime_forever"=>48,`

So the issue lies in the 'for' section of the partial, I'm thinking. Would I need to run the for in the main document, and feed it data from the partial? That seems of...

Comment: This question originated as a follow-up from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948354/api-search-on-rails-search-input)

Comment: `XXXXXX is actually a number, so I don't stringify it(Do I?)` - should be good to pass as a number.

Comment: `<%= steamId %>` this should be correct - as long as `steamId` is not null. though Rails standard naming practice is to use `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` (ie you'd normally call it `steam_id`) :) Note: to double-check you have something, you can use `inspect` - which will output `nil` if there is actually nothing in the variable eg: `<h1><%= steam_id.inspect %></h1>` (when I'm double-checking values I often use an h1 tag so it doesn't get lost in the page)

Comment: `<% puts steamId %>` will not work... it will output the value into your server-logs only (not onto the page), and make sure you have the equals-sign in the `<%=` tag or it will likewise not be output to the page

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @TarynEast. I'm not sure why <%= steamId %> works - I don't know if it's because of a <%= INSIDE of an <%= (Since it's already pulling the ERB?) But I was able to prove the number is sending, but the API is doing nothing with it. Trying to  see if maybe it's the `for` loop breaking it now.

Answer (score 0):

Is game_list a partial or is it a regular view? A partial will begin with an underscore as the file name. _game_list.html.erb

Try this

```
<%= render 'game_list', :header => "Welcome to His Page!", :steamId => XXXXXXXXXX %>
```

Then you can render steam ID like this `<%= steamId %>` inside of the partial.

Edit:

If you are not referencing steamId in direct output area you don't need to wrap it in <%= %>
Try `SteamWebApi::Player.‌​new(steamId)` instead of SteamWebApi::Player.‌​new(<%= steamId %>)

Another Edit

Try this

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(steamId)
   owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
This is my steam ID <%= steamId %>
<% owned_games.each do |game| %>
<%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
<% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
<%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
<% end %>
<%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

I added

```
This is my steam ID <%= steamId %>
```

Comment: `_game_list.html.erb` - It's a partial.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')' ...yer = SteamWebApi::Player.new(<%= steamId} ;@output_buffer.s... ... ^`
Is reply I get from this, as well.

My call being a bit diff because it's 
`<%= render :partial => 'game_list', :locals => {:header => "Welcome to His Page!", :steamId => "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" } %>`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply - That's one of the ways it doesn't error, but it doesn't render either (Nothing is there). Is there an ERB version of 'console.log' I can use to see what it assums steamId is once the page loaded?

Comment: Ahh, that worked. So why wouldn't the API be returning the results it normally would? 
`This is my steam ID 123456` Is it trying to run the API BEFORE the number is posted?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the Partial I had used as a template. It never modified the array of 'games' into 'game', so when it was iterating through the games 'each' it never returned any results.

My final partial works as intended.

```
<h1><%= header %></h1>
<% player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(steamId) %>
<% owned_games = player.owned_games(include_appinfo: true)%>
<% game = owned_games.games %>
<% games.each do |game| %>
  <%= game['playtime_2weeks'] %>
  <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
    <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= game['name'] %><br>
<% end %>
```

Once I added the additional modifier, it was able to render the list successfully.